# How can I get whole row with distinct column in hibernate using hql?

Tags: hibernate, hql, distinct

Name of table-test

```
Id      Name      Profession
1        a         Engg
2        b         Engg
3        c         Doctor
4        d         Doctor
```

Desired Output:

```
 Id      Name      Profession
 1        a         Engg
 4        d         Doctor
```

I want to get rows containing unique profession as shown in the table above. I tried

hql-

> "select distinct profession from test"

It's returning String profession. How  can I get whole row?

Comment: How to select id for that because in for Engg you selected 1 but for Doctor you selected 4

Comment: Id can be random. I just need one row for engg & one for doctor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DISTINCT` will return only column with unique value.

Instead of :

```
select distinct profession from test
```

Use below hql query:

```
select * from test group by profession
```

Comment: Thanks It's working . But I am always getting a and c I mean first element of both professions. Is there any way we can get random values rather than always first?

Comment: @DevenderYadav : I don't think so.

Comment: This does the job!